# Perl DBI connecting to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi, oracle12c

I'm using Perl DBI & trying to connect to Oracle 12c. I get an error:

> DBI connect('host=serverip;sid=comms;port=1521','comms',...) failed:
>   ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol (DBD ERROR:
>   OCISessionBegin)

My connection is:

> DBI->connect($connectionString, $user, $passwd,{PrintError=>1,
>   RaiseError=>1, AutoCommit=>1})

Would like to know if DBI can connect to Oracle 12c? Should I change to use something else?

Am new to Perl, so any help very much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the **sqlnet.ora file**. The parameters might not be same for the sqlnet.ora file in the **client-side** and **server-side**.

Since you have not posted all the details, there could be more than one issue. however, the most common is the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION`.

Read the [Database Net Services Reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006) for more details on **Parameters for the sqlnet.ora File**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Added SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION = 8 & able to connect now.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is always of the form: "dbi:Oracle:" There are several ways to identify a database:

1. If the database is local, specifying the SID or service name will be
   enough.
2. If the database is defined in a TNSNAMES.ORA file, you can use the
   service name given in the file
3. To connect without TNSNAMES.ORA file, you can use an EZCONNECT url,
   of the form: //host[:port][/service_name]